# DirectX - Access denied when creating swap chain for CoreWindow

Tags: c#, uwp, directx, sharpdx

I'm currently trying to create a swapchain for a CoreWindow using the latest SharpDX as DirectX wrapper and UWP as project base framework.

The documentation on that is so sparse it's unbelievable. Nonetheless I could find a snippet which looked promising. Inititally I always got an **E_INVALIDCALL** error message. Now it's "only" **E_ACCESSDENIED**.

So far I've done this to set up the chain:

```
var description = new SwapChainDescription1
{
    BufferCount = 2,
    Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.FlipSequential,
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    Width = 0,
    Height = 0,
    Scaling = Scaling.None,
    Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
    Stereo = false
};

CoreWindow window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
if (window == null)
{
    Logging.Error("Could not retrieve core window for swap chain.");
    throw new Exception("Invalid core window.");
}

using (var device = _device.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device2>())
{
    device.MaximumFrameLatency = 1;
    using (Adapter adapter = device.Adapter)
    {
        using (ComObject coreWindow = new ComObject(window))
        {
            using (Factory2 factory = adapter.GetParent<Factory2>())
                _swapChain = new SwapChain1(factory, _device, coreWindow, ref description);
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor of `SwapChain1` throws the SharpDX exception:

> SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
>   SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2.CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(ComObject deviceRef, ComObject windowRef, SwapChainDescription1& descRef, Output restrictToOutputRef, SwapChain1 swapChainOut)
>   SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain1..ctor(Factory2 factory, ComObject device, ComObject coreWindow, SwapChainDescription1& description, Output restrictToOutput)
>   RobInspect.Visualizer.Rendering.RenderingPanel.InitializeSizeDependentResources()
>   RobInspect.Visualizer.Rendering.RenderingPanel.InitializeDevice()
>
> "HRESULT: [0x80070005], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_ACCESSDENIED/General access denied error], Message: Access is denied.
>   "

Can anyone explain me why? "Access denied" is quite a broad statement and I'm not that experienced with DirectX's internals.

Further information: The code is executing on the main (UI) thread. So I guess I can exclude that the CoreWindow reference is inaccessible. Since this is first-time initialisation I also exclude the possibility of DirectX objects not being freed properly before creating the swap chain.

**EDIT**:
That's  the code for creating the device. Whereas the flags are set to *DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSuuport* and *DeviceCreationFlags.Debug*. The levels are set to *FeatureLevel.Level_11_1* down to *FeatureLevel.Level_9_1*.

```
using (var device = new Device(DriverType.Hardware, flags, levels))
{
    _device = device.QueryInterface<Device1>();
    _context = _device.ImmediateContext1;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need SharpDX? Maybe Win2d will perform your intentions? It's a lightweight Direct2D C# wrapper.

Comment: I successfully ran the code on a blank UWP project without any issues. Constructor of SwapChain1 runs without exceptions. How do you create the device instance?

Comment: Since I need to render a 3D model in real-time, yes I do. Okay that's weird... I use the constructor `using (var device = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(Hardware, flags, levels))` and then query for `Device1` (not sure - gonna update this in about an hour when I'm at work). Levels is set to *11_1* down to *9_3*. Flags is set to *BgraSupport* and *Debug*.

Comment: Updated it. And I just tried it in a new project and got it running as well. Now the price question is: Why does it not work. I guess I can exclude SharpDX objects as source. Possible source of the issue could be the `CoreWindow` instance. I am using DevExpress suite where in it I found that they seem to use SharpDX or DirectX interally to render certain things. At least I found similiar classes. Could it be blocking? But normally it should be possible to create and assign multiple swap chains after all.

Comment: Okay. Nailed it down to the CoreWindow. By creating a new view and using it's window, I can create a swap chain without any issues.

Comment: Okay. After enabling native debugging I found out that the source of the problem is an exception that says: *DCOMPOSITION_ERROR_WINDOW_ALREADY_COMPOSED*. So I figured it may be a problem that I initialize the device after app start on some page. I tried running the code in the application startup method and now it works. Guess the solution is to create device on startup and assign it later once you need it.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz did you actually run the project until the view was visible? In my test project I experience the same issue as with my project: It does create the DX objects but it fires an exception without stack trace which says *DCOMPOSITION_ERROR_WINDOW_ALREADY_COMPOSED*.

Comment: I get the same error. You can find more info on this error [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437369(v=vs.85).aspx). You may need to create another question for this issue.

Comment: Found the solution finally. I'll post it as answer so it's clearly visible for others.

Comment: I am getting this error seemingly at random sometimes when recreating the swap chain, but my app does not use XAML at all, it is pure C++/CX in UWP. Did you happen to find any non-XAML resources related to this error?

Comment: @LB-- No, sorry. I guess there shouldn't be much difference though as WinRT/XAML is also mostly native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that the terms **WinRT Core** and **WinRT XAML** are rather misleading. Since UWP is based on `CoreWindow` and both support and use them it's not clear where to use what.

DirectX exposes two methods for *WinRT* and one for *Desktop*. One being `Factory2.CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(...)` and one `Factory2.CreateSwapChainForComposition(...)`. The difference is that one takes the `CoreWindow` as parameter and one does not. And here's the trap I fell into.

**Core** stands for the design-scheme with which one only uses `IFrameworkView` and `IFrameworkViewSource` (see [here](https://qiita.com/ousttrue/items/c2588048563c18ad415f) for an example with SharpDX) whereas **XAML** stands for the traditional scheme where you have the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application` class.

When using the Core-model you have to call the `...ForCoreWindow(...)` method in order to create a swap chain. While using the XAML based approach you need a composition swap chain. I for myself already tried that, but failed because I forgot to enable (tip: do this if not already done) native debugging so the DirectX Debug Layer actually showed me essential information which could have saved me hours if not days of trial and error.

The issue here is that both composition and CoreWindow swap chains require special settings in the `SwapChainDescription1`. I'll leave you with the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop#swapchainpanel-and-gaming). Moreover if native debugging and the debug layer is enabled, DirectX will tell you exactly what setting is invalid.